# Adding an LDAP user to a local group

Tags: ubuntu, users, group, ldap

My host running Ubuntu 16.04 is also an LDAP client. The LDAP database contains some users like `ldapuser` who are able to log in the host.

`ldapuser` can join a *local* group like `sudo`, `sambashare`, etc., the same way as a local user.

Other than `ldapuser` unavailability when LDAP server is offline, are there any other disadvantages when LDAP users join local groups? Or are they always treated by the system the same way as the local users?